# How can I specify a @filterColumn and @filterValue in my where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to be able to dynamically specify the column on which to filter the query and the value to filter by.

The following `where` clause is giving me the error on each `case when` line

> an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

```
declare @filterColumn varchar(30) = 'Firstname'
declare @filterValue varchar(120) = 'Dave'

[select statement].....
where

    case when @filterColumn = 'Firstname' THEN Firstname END,

    case when @filterColumn = 'Lastname' THEN Lastname END,

    case when @filterColumn = 'StatusId' THEN u.Status END,

    case when @filterColumn = 'CreatedDate' THEN u.CreatedDate END,

like @filterValue
```

How can I fix this so that I can get the correct column to filter the results on.

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem, if I am honest. Such requirements normally mean you have one. Why don't you want 4 parameters, one for each column? If you "must" go down this route, you have to use dynamic SQL really, and **safely** inject the parameters. Why do you want/need to do this in the first place?

Comment: The requirement is that the user can specify the column & value at runtime. I feels like it wouldn't make sense to have a growing number of parameters, especially when there are many more than what I demonstrated with in the question.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is prob the way to go, but make sure to parameterize it properly. **DO NOT** interpolate the params direct into the query.

Comment: Discussed by Erland in great detail in his [dynamic search conditions page](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Comment: But you have different data types. Looking at your example I would suggest you have 3 different data types there, `nvarchar`, `int` and `date`; you can't have a parameter with a varying data type. I would, personally, urge that this is not a route you want to go down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.  This will allow you to cast the FilterValue and use something other than Like since Like doesn't really work with date types

```
declare @filterColumn varchar(30) = 'Firstname'
declare @filterValue varchar(120) = 'Dave'

[select statement].....
where
    ((@filterColumn = 'Firstname' and Firstname like @filterValue) or @filterColumn <> 'Firstname')
    and ((@filterColumn = 'Lastname' and Lastname like @filterValue) or @filterColumn <> 'Lastname')
    and ((@filterColumn = 'StatusId' and u.Status like @filterValue) or @filterColumn <> 'StatusId')
    and ((@filterColumn = 'CreatedDate' and u.CreatedDate = @filterValue) or @filterColumn <> 'CreatedDate')
option (recompile)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't get the others to work but this one did. Could you please explain what `option (recompile)` does in this context?

Comment: I typically use this in queries that have dynamic where clauses if the tables are very large and constantly changing. It might not be beneficial in your case since its just checking the same parameters in every `and`.  I would try without it first, and change the `@filterColumn` to see if the query runs fast no matter the value.  If its fast with one value but always slow with others, then try `option (recompile)`

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but very relevent to the area of SQL you're headed to:

- http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

For now though, the syntax you're trying to accomplish is...

```
WHERE
    CASE @filterColumn
      WHEN 'Firstname'   THEN Firstname
      WHEN 'Lastname'    THEN Lastname
      WHEN 'StatusId'    THEN u.Status
      WHEN 'CreatedDate' THEN u.CreatedDate
    END
    LIKE
    @filterValue
```

This assumes that all the columns can be cast to the same relevant datatype; a string.

Be warned though, as per comments on your question, and the article linked at the top of my answer, this pattern is far from ideal, from a SQL engine perspective.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, I would avoid this idea, and instead use 4 parameters. As it seems, however, that you need at least 1 not `NULL` value, and likely will be only provided 1 parameter (though this works for 1+), I suggest a dynamic statement, so that you don't have poorly cached query plans. This ends up with a query like the following:

```sql
--These are your parameters
DECLARE @FirstName nvarchar(50),
        @LastName nvarchar(50),
        @StatusId int,
        @CreatedDate date;

--NOw for the solution
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT {Your Columns}' + @CRLF + --obviously replace with your actual columns
           N'FROM dbo.YourTable' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE ' +
           STUFF(CONCAT(CASE WHEN @FirstName IS NOT NULL THEN @CRLF + N'  AND FirstName = @FirstName' END,
                        CASE WHEN @LastName IS NOT NULL THEN @CRLF + N'  AND FirstName = @FirstName' END,
                        CASE WHEN @StatusID IS NOT NULL THEN @CRLF + N'  AND FirstName = @FirstName' END,
                        CASE WHEN @CreatedDate IS NOT NULL THEN @CRLF + N'  AND FirstName = @FirstName' END),1,8,N'') + N';';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@FirstName nvarchar(50), @LastName nvarchar(50), @StatusId int, @CreatedDate date', @FirstName, @LastName, @StatusID, @CreatedDate;
```